# Samba4 on HPUX 11.31

Tags: samba, active-directory, hp-ux

I'm tryng to setup hpux samba,i use this
smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = DOMINIO
    realm = DOMINIO.COM
    server string = ""
    netbios name = HPUX2
        security = ads
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.1
        debug level = 10
        log file = /var/opt/samba4/log/%m.log
        max log size = 50
        log level = 1
        syslog = 0
        template shell = /usr/local/bin/bash
        template homedir = /home/%U
        winbind separator = /
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        encrypt passwords = yes
        invalid users = root
        local master = yes
        domain master = no
        preserve case = yes
        short preserve case = no
        default case = lower
        case sensitive = no
    map to guest = never
    restrict anonymous = 2
    hide dot files = yes
    guest account = smbnull


[Pubblica]
   comment = Dir pubblica
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = no
   public = yes
   path = /var/pubblica
   writable = yes
```

When i try to join AD(samba4) it create the hpux computer on computers ou
of AD,but fail with this error

```
Failed to join domain: failed to connect to AD: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
```

Kinit works fine,and krb5.conf are ok
I see also spn entries were created
but wbinfo -g and wbinfo -u report fail
On server log i see

```
  receive_smb_raw_talloc failed for client ipv4:192.168.0.16:51845 read error = NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE.
```

I try both samba4 compiled by me and cifs-server of hpux

For help this is the krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = DOMINIO.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 allow_weak_crypto = true

[realms]
 DOMINIO.COM = {
 }

[domain_realm]
 .dominio.com = DOMINIO.COM
 dominio.com = DOMINIO.COM
```

Comment: Anything else in the log files that might help? (i.e. /var/opt/samba4/log/*)?  Or even in the standard system log?

Comment: This error give with debug mode: krb5_set_default_tgs_ktypes failed (Program lacks support for encryption type)
ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed with: Program lacks support for encryption type, calling kinit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried samba hp(called hp cifs server)
on hpux 11.23,and works fine also with samba4 server.
The problem is the new hp cifs server
the only server wich work on 11.31 with samba4 is 03.02.00
the newest release doesn't work
EDIT: The latest version 03.02.04 works fine with latest samba 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.
The only way to get hpux 11.31 joined to ad samba4 with ads
is
a)recompile yourself krb5 mit(is possible,removing from Makefile pedantic and werror)
b)recompile samba3 after install krb5 mit using this configure

```
 ./configure --prefix=/opt/samba3 --with-lockdir=/var/opt/samba3/locks --with-privatedir=/var/opt/samba3/private --sysconfdir=/etc/opt/samba3 --localstatedir=/var/opt/samba3 --with-krb5=/opt/krb5  CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/krb5/include' LDFLAGS=' -L/opt/krb5/lib -Wl,+b,/opt/krb5/lib -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err'
```

c)Use smb.conf like this,don't forget to create a smbnull user before

```
[global]
        workgroup = DOMINIO
    realm = DOMINIO.COM
    server string = ""
    netbios name = HPUX2
        security = ads
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24 127.0.0.1
        debug level = 10
        log file = /var/opt/samba4/log/%m.log
        max log size = 50
        log level = 1
        syslog = 0
        template shell = /usr/local/bin/bash
        template homedir = /home/%U
        winbind separator = /
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        encrypt passwords = yes
        invalid users = root
        local master = yes
        domain master = no
        preserve case = yes
        short preserve case = no
        default case = lower
        case sensitive = no
    map to guest = never
    restrict anonymous = 2
    hide dot files = yes
    guest account = smbnull
```

d)Then fix some library error editing /etc/SHLIB_PATH or export SHLIB_PATH
and run daemons smbd,nmbd,winbindd
join AD as usual with net ads join
test it with wbinfo